# RC circuit How does the current vary after the switch is closed?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current

[image: , i]

in the image below : a quiz from the book "physics for scientists and engineers" in chapter 28 dicussing direct current circuts and RC circuits

i need an explanation for the answers for this quiz which i don't  understand how it goes , the answers are c,d

Comment: To transients, a capacitor is an open circuit. In steady state, capacitors are an open circuit. Did you read this section of the book completely?

Comment: i agree with you ,but at the moment  after  the switch is closed ,  the capacitor  act like an open circuit  , and  this the way i though  ,  but that will lead me to cancel out the loop of  the capacitor as it's opened and this is not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On simplified level you can see a capacitor in a DC circuit like this:

When it's uncharged (just the moment you close the switch) it's like closed switch.

When it's fully charged (in your quiz called after very long time) it's like a open switch.

Lets call the Resistor closer to the battery \$R_1\$ and the other one \$R_2\$.

So this answers your question:

1. In the moment the switch is beeing closed you have current flowing through both resistors:

\$I_1=\frac{U}{R_1}\$

and

\$I_2=\frac{U}{R_2}\$

The total current is:

\$I_{Total} = I_1 + I_2\$

And since \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are same the result is

\$I_{Total} = \frac{2*U}{R}\$

Note that this is only valid for exactly the moment the switch is beeing closed (where the capacitor is fully discharged).

2. When the capacitor is fully charged this part of the circuit has no current flowing anymore so \$I_{Total}\$ come down to beeing \$I_1\$ which is

\$I_1 = \frac{U}{R}\$

Comment: thanks for your answer , just i want to ensure from something did he mean by" after a long time"--in the question-- that capacitor is fully charged